# Display Liferay Version in Liferay DXP 7.4 design fragment

Tags: liferay-7.4

I'd like to show the Liferay version for example in a page footer fragment, but searching the web did not help.
Is there any Liferay version variable I can use in a Liferay DXP 7.4 design fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further web digging and testing did the trick.

In https://learn.liferay.com/w/dxp/site-building/developer-guide/reference/fragments/fragment-specific-tags-reference I found a hint regarding the syntax

```
${someUtil.someMethod(...)}
```

Since I'm in a Docker installation I have an env var

```
LIFERAY_RELEASE_VERSION=2023.q4.0
```

which I also see in the control panel as

```
env.LIFERAY_RELEASE_VERSION
```

So all I had to do in my fragment is

```
${propsUtil.get("env.LIFERAY_RELEASE_VERSION")}
```

to see 2023.q4.0 in the output.